# Queremos ter anúncios da comunidade? Se sim, de que tipo?

Tags: debate, community-ads

Muito obrigado a [@CypherPotato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24529/cypherpotato) pela tradução.

---

Muitos sites da Stack Exchange são até populares (em outras palavras, eles tem bastantes visualizações por página). Nós utilizamos uma porção destas visualizações para anúncios pagos. [Nós fazemos isso com cautela, sem sobrecarregar os sites](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/25/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/). Até mesmo com os anúncios pagos, nós continuamos tendo um excesso enorme de inventário de anúncios.

#### [Neste ano, estamos feliz em oferecer a comunidade a usarem seus espaços para anúncios no Stack Overflow em Português.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/)

Por favor, compartilhe o que você pensa sobre:

1. Gostariam de ter anúncios comunitários no site ou é melhor sem eles?
2. Se você quer anúncios comunitários, que tipo de anúncios poderiam ser?

#### Tipos de anúncios comunitários

Todas as comunidades da Stack Exchange são encorajadas a promover:

- Atividades sociais e comunitárias nos metas dos sites.
- Ferramentas e aplicações de código aberta / gratuitas relatadas ao site.
- Conferências ou outros eventos que seriam interessantes aos usuários.
- Qualquer coisa que a comunidade estaria genuinamente interessada em.

Existe apenas um site que é exceção - Stack Overflow em Inglês. Este tem uma restrição adicional: [anúncios poderiam solicitar a participação e contribuição de programadores escrevendo atualmente código aberto](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/19/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Nosso site está bem próximo ao Stack Overflow em Inglês. Parece que poderíamos ter uma restrição similar... ou não?

O que você pensa sobre? Você quer anúncios comunitários? Se sim, que tipos de anúncios comunitários seriam permitidos no SOpt? Compartilhe suas ideias!

Note que nós reservamos o direito de exercer controle editorial e não permitir qualquer anúncio que não estaríamos confortáveis em ser publicado no site.

Comment: O texto e fácil de traduzir o problema é essa frase " we still have a lot of excess ad inventory.", não sei a traduzir para o português talvez ficasse assim "ainda assim continuamos com excesso de ofertas nos ads"

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado! Só queria dizer que temos um grande número de impressões não utilizadas que podemos usar para anúncios da comunidade.

Answer (score 14):

Eu gostaria de ver anúncios de vagas de trabalho, assim como acontece no StackOverflow.com

Acredito que esse é o tipo de "banner" que ajudaria muito mais a comunidade de várias formas, principalmente nesse momento de incerteza.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106405/discussion-on-answer-by-hugocsl-queremos-ter-anuncios-da-comunidade-se-sim-de) - quem tiver interesse em ler ou prosseguir, clique no link.

Answer (score 8):

Não tenho nada contra se realmente for bem controlado e não exagerado.

Minha dúvida é se pode ser desligado se percebermos que está trazendo mais problema que solução. Imagino que sim e isso é importante.

Precisa ser relevante ao programador, não acho que deveria ter qualquer coisa fora disso, então só o último que fica um pouco em aberto. Gosto especialmente de promover projetos abertos. Imagino que a comunidade definirá se precisa ser só o que é feito para o público lusófono ou não (acho que deveria haver prioridade mas não exclusividade).

Parece que os critérios usados no SOen está ok, mas não tenho maiores informações.

Comment: Quanto a relevância de conteúdo tem ser que ser uma coisa certeira, por exemplo no youtube meus ads estão direcionados para programação e quando não vem WIX vem LOL e isso me incomoda bastante, já fiz reclamação e a resposta é sempre um texto padrão.

Comment: Até onde eu sei no SO eles analisam bem, não é automático, não é zona só pra fazer dinheiro, não sei se mudou pq eu não vejo ads :D

Comment: Acho que podemos parar de exibir anúncios, se precisarmos.

Comment: Clarificação: os anúncios em questão seriam como [estes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/1328704), e não os anúncios pagos por empresas — quer dizer, portanto, que a curadoria dos anúncios é feita por vocês, a comunidade, e não pela empresa (ainda que imponhâmos algumas restrições, e reservemos o direito a remover anúncios que não correspondam às regras definidas).

Comment: @JNat achei que teria os dois. O que não seria problema, mas tendo só essas acho mais tranquilo ainda.