# Community Ads 2020

Tags: debate, community-ads

Muito obrigado a [@Cesar M](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144721/cesar-m) pela tradução.

---

É hora de testar algo novo! Estamos iniciando no Stack Overflow em Português anúncios gratuitos, baseados em votos, para projetos Open Source.

Essa é a sua chance de criar um [Anúncio gratuito baseado em voto para Projetos Open Source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Crie um anúncio gráfico para um projeto open source de programação e coloque-o como resposta a esta pergunta (no formato correto), e ele entrará para a lista de anúncios no Stack Overflow em Português.

### Requisitos

[Baseado em uma discussão anterior](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8281/17539) e na experiência no Stack Overflow em Inglês, decidimos começar com os seguintes requisitos.

Deve ser um anúncio **solicitando a participação e contribuição de programadores para escrita de código**. A intenção não é anunciar os produtos apenas porque eles são Open Source, mas sim encontrar programadores que ajudarão com o código ou outras coisas de programação (documentação, revisão de código, corrigir problemas etc.).

Para isso funcionar, as respostas à essa pergunta **devem** estar de acordo com as regras.

### Template de resposta

```
[![Texto alternativo caso a imagem não seja mostrada][1]][2]

  [1]: http://url-da-imagem
  [2]: http://url-do-clique
```

Por favor **não adicione nada mais ao corpo da resposta**. Se você quiser adicionar comentários, faça isso nos comentários.

### Requisitos da imagem

- A imagem que você criar deve ter **300 por 250 pixels**, ou duas vezes isso se for de alto DPI.
- Deve ser hospedada no nosso host de imagens padrão (imgur)
- Deve ser GIF ou PNG
- Não pode ser um GIF animado
- Limite absoluto do tamanho do arquivo: **150 KB**
- Deve ter uma borda de 1px se (parte do) fundo for branco. 2px se for uma imagem de alto DPI.
- O texto dos anúncios deve estar em português.

O resultado, que será servido como um anúncio no Stack Overflow em Português pode ser previsto nesta URL:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Mínimo de votos

Há um **mínimo de pontuação** que uma resposta deve atingir (atualmente 6) antes que seja mostrada naquela URL e no Stack Overflow em Português. Você pode ver todos os anúncios que atualmente estão dentro do mínimo e dos nossos critérios nesta página:

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/8338

Comment: Agora meu game sair do papel.

Comment: Imagino que o projeto tenha que ter no minimo um código de conduta ou critérios bem definidos na parte que deseja buscar apoio, como um tipo de manual para colaborar com códigos, documentação e outros. Ou isto é irrelevante?

Comment: Eu acho que seria legal estender isso para comunidades locais também (de meetups, por exemplo). O que você acha, Nicolas? Podemos tentar ou precisaríamos de aprovação antes?